# treegrid with json in jqgrid (adjacency), jqgrid not displaying data with json?

Tags: xml, json, jqgrid, treeview

I am having troubles in finding examples in how to convert this xml in json for the jqgrid in adjacency model, the xml works, but in the docs there are no examples in json [docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadjacency_model), so can someone guide me in convert this xml in json??, I am still figuring out how to do it, help really apreciated

this is my code:

```
if ( stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"],"application/xhtml+xml") ) {
        header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"); } else {
        header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['nodeid'])==FALSE) {
    $node =0;
}
else{
    $node = (integer)$_REQUEST["nodeid"];
}
$clsJqGrid = new redCuidadana();
$et = ">";
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?$et\n";
echo "<rows>";
echo "<page>1</page>";
echo "<total>1</total>";
echo "<records>1</records>";

if($node >0) { //check to see which node to load
   $wh = 'parent_id='.$node; // parents
   //$n_lvl = $n_lvl+1; // we should ouput next level
} else {
   //$wh = 'ISNULL(parent_id)'; 
   $wh ='parent_id=0';// roots
}
$mostrarRegistros= $clsJqGrid->mostrarRegistros($wh);
foreach ($mostrarRegistros as $row){
   echo "<row>";         
   echo "<cell>".$row["id_ciudadano"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["distrito"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["seccion"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["rol"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["clave_electoral"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["nombre"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["apaterno"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["amaterno"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["level"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell><![CDATA[".$row["parent_id"]."]]></cell>";
   if($row["level"] == "2"){echo "<cell>"."true"."</cell>";}
   else{echo "<cell>".$row["isLeaf"]."</cell>";}
   echo "<cell>".$row["expanded"]."</cell>";
   echo "</row>";
}
echo "</rows>";
?>
```

this is what I have so far

```
    <?php
require_once '../../sesion/model/clsSesion.php';
require_once '../../red_ciudadana/model/modelRedCuidadana.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['nodeid'])==FALSE) {
    $node =0;
}
else{
    $node = (integer)$_REQUEST["nodeid"];
}

if($node >0) {
    $wh = 'parent_id='.$node;
    }
    else{

    $wh ='parent_id=0';
    }


header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

$response->total = 1;
$response->page = 1;
$response->records = $count=1;
$i=0;

$clsJqGrid = new redCuidadana();
$mostrarRegistros= $clsJqGrid->mostrarRegistros($wh);

foreach ($mostrarRegistros as $row){

    if($row["level"] == "2"){$cosa= "true";}
        else{$cosa=$row["isLeaf"];}

     $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row["id_ciudadano"];
     $row["expanded"];
     $response->rows[$i]['cell']= array($row["distrito"],
     $row["seccion"],
     $row["rol"],
     $row["clave_electoral"],
     $row["nombre"],
     $row["apaterno"],
     $row["amaterno"],
     $row["level"],
     $row["parent_id"],
     $cosa, 
     $row["expanded"]
     );

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**But the jqgrid is not displaying data**, this is the json I get

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["01","1001","Coordinador Distrital","ACBJ1975000001","JOSE RAUL","ACEVES","BARRIGA","0","0","false","false"]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know php, but this is how I do it in c# (ASP.NET MVC3): This is for an autoloading tree, not load tree at once.

Action method:

```
public JsonResult GetSPTreeJSON(string nodeid, string n_level, string currentUser)
        {
            List<TreeNode> list = _clientService.GetTreeNodeList(nodeid, n_level);

            var jsonData = new
            {
                page = 1,
                total = 1,
                records = 1,
                rows = (
                    from TreeNode u in list
                    select new
                    {
                        cell = new object[] { u.Id.ToString(), u.name, u.level, u.ParentId, u.isLeaf, false }
                    }).ToList()
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Method where the list of TreeNodes is built up:

```
public List<TreeNode> GetTreeNodeList(string nodeid, string n_level)
    {
        List<Tree> root = null;

        Guid? currentNode;
        if (nodeid == null)
            currentNode = null;
        else
            currentNode = new Guid(nodeid);

        if (nodeid == null) 
            root = ssdsContext.Trees.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList(); 
        else
            root = ssdsContext.Trees.Where(x => x.ParentId == currentNode).ToList();

        List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>();

        int newLevel = n_level == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(n_level) + 1;

        foreach (Tree t in root)
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode
            {
                expanded = false,
                Id = t.UserId,
                isLeaf = t.IsUser,
                name = t.Name,
                ParentId = t.ParentId,
                level = newLevel
            };
            list.Add(n);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

TreeNode Class:

```
public class TreeNode
    {
        public Guid Id;
        public string name;
        public int level;
        public Guid? ParentId;
        public bool isLeaf;
        public bool expanded;
    }
```

Sample JSON (note our ids are GUIDS):

```
{
   "page":1,
   "total":1,
   "records":1,
   "rows":[
      {
         "cell":[
            "29846baa-ede0-4582-b9ed-39bcc486f2c2", //Id
            "Level1 Group", //Name
            1, //Level
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006", //Parent Id
            false, //Is Leaf
            false //Expanded
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "fd62f214-e25c-4d68-aa38-6805adfb4305",
            "Level1 Group",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            false,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "39cc2783-811f-4885-9af6-d35b1a1385a2",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "5a1a9743-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "466d78df-6f39-43ff-abfd-58e7bf91f8c8",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "c80ca2d1-8210-4c11-8c6d-005c97fce9cb",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "d1f870ed-bca6-4cc8-8b96-b19fa251c2f8",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "3061ce07-bff6-4d9a-a84a-a8a7d47ebd7a",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "d9dadce8-a9ce-4343-a8a0-b80844aa36ad",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      },
      {
         "cell":[
            "9042ded8-09ee-46f9-beac-8746ed1cdd17",
            "Level 1 Node",
            1,
            "5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006",
            true,
            false
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Maybe it will be easy for you to convert.

Comment: let me know if you have any questions